# Diferença entre "terráqueo", "terrestre" e "terrícola"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, diferenças, substantivos, definição

Em português há três palavras com significado de *earthling* do inglês, "terráqueo", "terrestre" e "terrícola". Qual é a diferença entre elas? Seria que "terráqueo" é mais usado no contexto de fição científica? Quando usar "terrícola" ou "terrestre"?

Comment: Diferença entre terráqueo, terrestre e terrícola? Não conhecia *terrícola*, é certo que aparece no dicionário, nas o meu corretor ortográfico pt_PT não o reconhece.

Comment: Concordância verbal: "em português **há**", ou "em português **tem**".

Comment: @ANeves I was thinking too much of the English "In Portuguese there **are** three words [...]". I don't quite understand intuitively why in Portuguese it would be different, but anyway, maybe in a different question.

Comment: It's... like "it rains". No one rains, "it" is just raining. In German it's the same, "auf Portuguiesisch **[es gibt](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_en.html#/search=es%20gibt)** drei Worter ..." (sort of "it exists" or "it has"). There's a sort of no-one as subject. Sorry, but today I can't explain because my brain is feeling "Monday-morning". ("Concordância" verbal? Com quê?!? Hoje estou pior que sei lá o quê...) Yes, open a question! :)

Comment: @Earthliŋ Don't feel so contrite. We say *em português exist**em** três palavras*. BTW where did you dig up *terrícola* from? I appear nobody else knew about it.

Comment: @Jacinto Here's what I think happened. I knew there were at least two words I had seen for "earthling" in Portuguese. I knew "terrestre" from Latin _terrestris_ and then tried to look up the words in a dictionary. But in Aurélio _terrestre_ is only listed as an adjective. Then I found _terrícola_ and thought I must have confused it with _terrestre_...

Comment: @Earthliŋ You're right. Dictionairies list all those three words as adjectives, but we are fairly relaxed about turning an adjective into a noun. But I've just found the legitimate noun you're looking for. I'm going to edit my answer sraight away.

Comment: I remember Terricola used once in a while in scifi books and comics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[***Terrestre***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/terrestre) tem vários significados: (1) relativo ao planeta Terra (crosta terrestre); (2) relativo à terra seca por oposição ao mar (o elefante é o maior animal terrestre, transportes terrestres por oposição a marítimos ou aéreos); (3) relativo ao mundo material, por oposição ao celestial ou espiritual (neste sentido é muito mais comum usar-se [*terreno*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/terreno), e.g. *felicidade terrena*).

[***Terráqueo***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/terr%C3%A1queo) significa segundo o Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (DACL) apenas relativo ao planeta Terra. Por isso a preferência por *terráqueo* para designar um natural do planeta Terra, já que *terrestre* tem outros significados.

[***Terrícola***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/terr%C3%ADcola) segundo o Priberam pode significar *terráqueo* ou que vive no interior do solo. Esta palavra não vem no DACL, e eu não a conhecia.

Agora com uma exceção todos os dicionários que consultei listam as palavras acima apenas como adjetivos. A exceção é [*terráqueo* no Dicio](http://www.dicio.com.br/terraqueo/) que  aparece também como substantivo.

Mas encontrei no Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa um substantivo, que também nunca tinha ouvido ou lido antes, e que significa habitante do planeta Terra. É ele (rufem tambores se fazem favor): terrígeno. Aparece nos dicionários online, [por exemplo no Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/terr%C3%ADgeno), mas apenas como adjetivo, com o significado de produzido ou gerado no solo.

Comment: Pois nem eu conhecia. Se eu colocar o dicionário do *browser* em pt_BR ele não dá erro, em pt_PT dá erro. Por isso talvez tenha origem no Brasil ou seja usada mais no Brasil.

Comment: @JorgeB. Nem me parece que seja muito (se calhar nem pouco) usada no Brasil. Se googlares *terrícola*, nas três primeiras páginas aparecem-te só dois sites em português, e são de dicionários. Tudo o resto é em castelhano. Deve ser mais um daqules fósseis linguísticos, como *alvalade*, que ninguém conhece. Bora perguntar ao Earthling one é que ele viu.

Comment: No Brasil nunca li ou ouvi a palavra "terrícola".

Comment: @jean Era o que eu suspeitava. É um verdadeiro fóssil linguístico que o Earthling desenterrou. Mas provavelmente também nunca ouviste a palavra que eu vou adicionar à minha resposta. Eu nunca a tinha encontrado antes.

Answer (score 2):

Inicialmente, concordo com as definições apresentadas: "terrestre" refere-se à terra firme (e aí temos animais aquáticos e animais terrestres), enquanto "terráqueo" refere-se ao planeta. Mas aí teríamos alienígenas definidos como extraterráqueos, sendo extraterrestres exatamente aqueles que não habitam a terra firme, como tubarões e baleias.

Comment: Sérgio, bem-vindo aqui à comunidade. As definições apresentadas com que concordas são quais, da pergunta (que não tem grandes definições) ou da outra resposta (a minha)? Seria bom clarificar isso. Até porque por omissão, como estás a responder à pergunta, supõe-se que seria as definições da pergunta, mas como ela não tem grandes definições... Seria bom clarificar isso. A tua lógica é interessante, mas a língua nem sempre se interessa por lógica :)

Comment: Referi-me às definições apresentadas ao longo das diversas respostas: "terrestre" referindo-se à terra firme e "terráqueo" referindo-se ao planeta Terra. O problema, como destaquei, é que segundo essa definição (com a qual concordo, insisto), qualquer manifestação explanetetária deveria ser definida como extraterráquea, não como extraterrestre. Será culpa de Spielberg com seu E.T.?

Comment: A expressão `extraterrestre` é bastante anterior ao filme. É possível que tenha sido causada pelo aportuguesamento da expressão equivalente da língua inglesa, mas certamente não por causa desta obra em específico.

Comment: Sérgio, esta tua nova "resposta" é um resposta ao meu comentário anterior, e deveria ter sido colocada lá. Deveria ter clicado "add a comment" e não "add another answer". Pedi aos moderadores para corrigirem ist. Tu tens que chegar a reputação 50 para poderes comentar outras perguntas e respostas, mas a tua própria resposta já podes comentar à vontade. Podes também modificá-la e acrescentar esclarecimentos (clica "edit").

Comment: Pois, o que acontece é que *terrestre* tem vários significados. Por exemplo, em *crosta terrestre* e *atmosfera terrestre*, "terrestre" refere-se ao planeta todo, e não só à terra seca.

Comment: @SergioRobertodeSouza não use o campo de respostas para comentar, para isso tem o link de comentar logo a baixo.